# Enabling Trackpoing scroll under Wayland for my IBM SpaceSaver II (RT3200)

Tags: 20.04, wayland, trackpoint

I have an old IBM SpaceSaver II that I've been using for a while now. After updating to Ubuntu 20.04 I decided to give Wayland another go. The only thing that keeps me from using it full time is the middle mouse click scroll not working.

Under X it wouldn't work out of the box either, but you could enable it by setting the scroll method via xinput:

`xinput --set-prop "USBPS2 Mouse" "libinput Scroll Method Enabled" 0, 0, 1`

But I haven't found a way to set this under Wayland.

In [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553458/414394) they change properties for a built-in trackpoint using `/etc/udev/hwdb.d`, but I'm not sure how to use it correctly and where to find the properties for a given device. I tried using:

```
evdev:name:USBPS2 Mouse
  MOUSE_SCROLL_METHOD=button
```

```
evdev:name:USBPS2 Mouse
  SCROLL_METHOD_ENABLED=button
```

```
evdev:name:USBPS2 Mouse
  SCROLL_METHOD_ENABLED=0,0,1
```

but it has no effect. Can you tell me if I'm on the right track here? How do I find out the properties for devices? Is there a way to validate the selector?

The keyboard is connected via a PS/2 to USB adapter, so it appears as **USBPS2** when listing libinput devices:

```
Device:           USBPS2
Kernel:           /dev/input/event18
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           USBPS2 Mouse
Kernel:           /dev/input/event19
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           USBPS2 Consumer Control
Kernel:           /dev/input/event20
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           USBPS2 System Control
Kernel:           /dev/input/event21
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a
```

As you can see the **USBPS2 Mouse** has the scroll method button available, but not enabled (at least I think so since there is no asterisk before it). For the integrated Trackpoint it works out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out while playing around with udev rules:

Turns out the issue is that ID_INPUT_POINTINGSTICK is not set, so I guess libinput does not fully recognize the device. Can be solved with a simple udev rule:

```
ACTION=="add|change", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0d3d", ATTRS{name}=="*USBPS2 Mouse*", ENV{ID_INPUT_POINTINGSTICK}="1"
```

This works for both Wayland and Xorg, no need to set it with `xinput --set-prop` anymore.